# Can't read and write files fast enough for my script to recognize changes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im writing a script that will eventually be able to tweet form a twitter account when my favourite YouTuber Casey Neistat uploads a new video. However, in order to do that, I wrote a program that (should) be able to compare a 'output.txt' file of all the links to his previous videos to a new one when it recognizes that the previous list of YouTube links does not include a recently uploaded video. I made two methods, one called 'mainloop' that runs over and over to see if a previous list of all Casey Neistat's videos is the same as a string of new links retrieved from the method 'getNeistatNewVideo'. However the problem i'm having, is that once the program recognizes a new video, it goes to the method 'getNewURL' that will take the first link recorded in the 'output.txt' file. But when I say to print this new URL, it says there is nothing there. My hunch is that this is because python is not reading and writing to the output.txt file fast enough, however I may be wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
import bs4
import requests
import re
import time
import tweepy


'''
This is the information required for Tweepy


CONSUMER_KEY =
CONSUMER_SECRET = 
ACCESS_KEY = 
ACCESS_SECRET = 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

End of Tweepy Information
'''

root_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
index_url = root_url + 'user/caseyneistat/videos'

def getNeistatNewVideo():

    response = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.yt-lockup-thumbnail a[href^=/watch]')]


def mainLoop():


    results = str("\n".join(getNeistatNewVideo()))

    past_results = open('output.txt').read()

    if results == past_results:
        print("No new videos at this time")

    else:
        print("There is a new video!")

        print('...')
        print('Writing to new text file')
        print('...')


        f = open("output.txt", "w")
        f.write(results)

        print('...')
        print('Done writing to new text file')
        print('...')

        getNewURL()

def getNewURL():

    url_search = open('output.txt').read()
    url_select = re.search('(.+)', url_search)
    print("New Url found: " + str(url_select))


while True:

    mainLoop()

    time.sleep(10)

    pass
```

Comment: How do you know that slow I/O is the issue? How's your main loop running? Infinitely or triggered by some push event? Does it pause? How large are the output files? Is string compare the culprit?

Comment: It runs infinitely. My apologies for a not-so-detailed post, I am very new to programming.

Comment: Ah just noticed you pause every 10 seconds. So 10s = 0s in latency of your method. Now how much time reading a page takes in your system? BSoup is also engaged in parsing the long youtube page everytime... such a page takes 5-10s just for downloading and parsing for my pc

Comment: How much time is it currently taking? Did you try changing that 10 second to some other value?

Comment: You likely need to close the file after writing to it. That is, after `f.write(results)`, put a `f.close()`. Even better, look into opening files with a so-called "context manager", also called a "with-statement". This will automatically close the file for you.

Comment: Turns out the file did need f.close() after it to work properly. Thanks jme!

Comment: Ahh perfect! Even I didn't see that - and even I keep forgetting to close the file handle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never close the files and that may be the problem. For instance, in `mainLoop()` you should have:

```
f = open("output.txt", "w")
f.write(results)
f.close()
```

or even better:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write(results)
```

In general, it's a good idea to use the `with` statement in all places where you open a file (even if it's in 'r' mode) as it automatically will take care of closing the file and it also makes it clear which section of the code is working on/with the file at a given time.